# CSS : Background image not rescaling on mobile

Tags: css, image, background, header

I'm not a coder but have some basic knowledge and have been editing a template. The site is almost there - on desktop it looks fine but on mobile the cover image doesn't scale down.

I've tried changing the size from 100%, auto and cover, played with vw and vh etc, but still can't get anything to work.

Here's the CSS:

```
.intro {
  display: table;    
  height: auto;    
  width: auto; /* 100% originally */ .   
  padding: 0;    
  text-align: center;    
  color: #333;    
  background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;    
  background-color: #e5e5e5;    
  -webkit-background-size: cover;    
  -moz-background-size: cover;    
  background-size: auto;    
  -o-background-size: auto;    
}
```

If anyone can help that would be great! the site is adammillsmusic.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Responsive Images do the following in .intro class

```
intro {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain
}
```

Key changes

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display:block;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are prefixing properties different values :

- `-webkit-background-size: cover;` : On webkit (Chrome & co), cover the background
- `background-size: auto;` On other browsers, do not cover

This is probably why you see a covered background on your desktop and having unexpected results on a mobile browser.

```css
body {
  display: table;    
  height: auto;    
  width: auto; /* 100% originally */ .   
  padding: 0;    
  text-align: center;    
  color: #333;    
  background: url(//placecage.com/200/200) no-repeat center top;    
  background-color: #e5e5e5;    
  background-size: cover;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `max-width` to 100% like this:

```
max-width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help - this did solve the problem. Though now after seeing the result, I think maybe it would be wiser to call a smaller size image through the use of '@media' for the mobile site. The only problem is in my code editor when I try to do this it doesn't seem to recognise the '@media' tag and treats it like /* */ 
Any thoughts?! Thanks

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.intro {background-color: #e5e5e5;
background: url(../img/Bg-mountain-small.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```